# Implementing Zurb Foundation 4 with Magento but getting conflict with prototype script

Tags: magento, zurb-foundation

I am trying to implement Zurb Foundation 4 with Magento and there is a conflict with prototype.js.
I'm using jQuery.noConflict() but seems like foundation.js script always call prototype "each" function instead of jQuery's.

error: TypeError: iterator.call is not a function - prototype.js (line 825)

This is where "each" is calld in foundation.js:

```
return jQuery(this).each(function () {
   Foundation.init.apply(Foundation, [this].concat(args));
   return this;
});
```

I tried to use jQuery(this).each instead of this.each but it did not work.
What I am doing wrong?
Does anyone have some other suggestion what to do or did someone managed to put this to work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have made some tests and seems that this will work for now. When you do the init of the foundation use this code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(document).foundation(function (response) {
        console.log(response.errors);
    });
});
```

You can comment "console.log(response.errors);". For furder information you can follow the the issue at https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/1929